# Is it generally possible to manually program network routers on how to direct traffic?

Tags: routing

Is it possible to somehow program or configure Ethernet router to direct all traffic from specific port to some other port bidirectionally (as if connecting devices are directly connected via Ethernet cable), while all other ports are routed normally? If yes, can you give me some key terms to google because all English wording I come up with are a dead end. Also, if yes, how "physical" is this connection? In a sense, if I put some arbitrary DC voltage on unused wires of 10/100A will the other device see it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> In a sense, if I put some arbitrary DC voltage on unused wires of 10/100A will the other device see it?

Probably you will fry the router's circuitry and nothing more.

The behavior that you are describing is that of a hub (stupid repeater), and even then....

You should get some basic understanding of the different layers:

1. Layer 1: physical connection: connection between machines, or between machines and some network gear like

   - a repeater/hub (layer 1 device),
   - a bridge/switch (layer 2 device), or
   - a router (layer 3 device)
2. Layer 2 and up: The signal on the wire is inspected by the circuitry of the device in order to decide which ports to forward it to.

I don't know what you are planning to do exactly, but in any case with classical network gear it is not possible.

Comment: Basically, I was hoping to use two "extra" pairs of wires of ethernet wiring to some arbitrary role, maybe power some devices or do some communicating with GPIO on RPi or something like that and was worried of exactly the things you warn about - burning my router. I have seen on wiki that PoE in mode B can take 48V DC on 4th and 5th. OTOH I have read that extra wiring is left available for analog phone so what happens to such signal if pushed through router?

Comment: If you are using Ethernet routers/switches you have Ethernet on the physical layer. (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ethernet_physical_layer) If you put an analog signal or whatever on it, in the best of cases nothing will happen. What you are looking for is some kind of general cabling switches that would allow you to "virtualize" wiring, much like for example integrated Ethernet/FibreChannel etc. switches do. I don't know if that exists, in any case I have never heard about it. Get it out of your mind. You have IT equipment here. :)

Comment: So noted, sir :)

Comment: Since you were talking about GPIO I need to throw in that depending on the protocol you wish to transmit over the network, there of course exist converters for some. Like this: http://www.lantronix.com/products/xdirect/

Answer (score 2):

A lot depends on the type of router you have.  Cisco calls it "policy based routing," but other manufacturers use other names.   And it is a logical connection, not a physical one.

Comment: So routing may be described as a digital reinterpretation of what has been seen on input port piped to output port. And thank you for mentioning PBR - that is exactly what I had in mind to start my googling.